# What are the mechanical benefits of having your PC being Legio Mortuum?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

I have been looking through *Requiem for Rome* and having troubles following the book or finding a section that tells the mechanical benefits of having a PC within the folds of the Legio Mortuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it on Page 78:

> Advantages: Members of the Legio Mortuum may purchase Resources, Fighting Style, Mentor and Retainer Merits at half the normal experience cost (rounding up). This cost break does not apply to the purchases of these Merits during character creation.